# "Decisiontable" in WIX

Tags: xml, wix, xmltable

I'm searching a way to create a Setup with WIX, which is loading settings from a xml-file (or only a simple table in the file) and modifies the features of the setup depending on the data in the xml/table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WiX doesn't have an xmlLocator pattern so you will have to write a custom action to read your dataset into properties.  From there it depends on what you mean by modify features.  Do you just mean hide, install or don't install the feature or do you have something more dynamic in mind?

If the former, you can use the properites you loaded in Condition elements to change the installLevel of the features relative to your INSTALLLEVEL property.   If you have something more complex in mind ( unlikely ) you would have to use a custom action to emit temporary rows into the feature / featurecomponents table.

Comment: Christopher,

Thanks for your answer. I have a bit more complex in mind. Currently I'm testing out the way with a vbs-script.

If I have some answer I'll post them here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use decisiontables on-line:

```
https://www.azaig.de/dt.html
```

This will produce a unique decisiontable-link to share.